# Extending a footer (without Javascript?)

Tags: html, css, colors, footer

I have a pretty run-of-the-mill website: header, body and footer. The header and body are green, but the footer is black. The site looks fine when there's a large amount of content, but on pages with only a paragraph or two, the footer doesn't extend to the bottom of the page (especially on larger monitors), and the green background of the site extends beyond the footer - not the effect I'm going for.

Is there a way to set the footer height to extend all the way to the bottom of the page, regardless of content and monitor size? Ideally this would be done without using Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a [sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).  I have had good experiences with [Ryan Fait's solution](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/), but this [new sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) manages to work without the extra tags.

From the [exposition on the sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html):

In the head:

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {height: 100%;}
#wrap {min-height: 100%;}
#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */
#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;} 
/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;/
}
</style>
<!--[if !IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
    #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

And for your body:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main">
    <!-- Your content here -->
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

### Edit

From your explanation, it seems that I misunderstood you. You are looking for an auto-expanding section, rather than a sticky footer.  If this is the case, you can get that effect by using [`display: table`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#table) (though it doesn't work in as many browsers as the sticky footers do - it fails in IE 7, for example).

I have created [an example here](http://jsbin.com/idozuk/edit).

The code, for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style type="text/css">
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .Wrapper {
    display: table;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .Contents {
    background-color: #CCC;
    display: table-row;
    min-height: 100px;
  }
  .Footer {
    background-color: #0C0;
    display: table-row;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
  .data {
     display: table-cell;
  }
.Wrapper .data {
  height: 100px;
}
.Footer .data {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 40px;
  background-color: #0C0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Wrapper">
<div class="Contents">
<p class="data">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div class="Footer">
<p class="data">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is actually not what I was looking for at all, and no other answers solved my problem. I ended up setting the <body> CSS background-color to the footer's color, then manually changing all other background-colors in the site.

Comment: @daysrunaway - am I correct in understanding that I misunderstood your original requirements ;-) ? Next time tell me, and I'll try and update the question sooner :-)  (And am I correct in my corrected understanding that you actually want the exact *opposite* of a sticky footer ... a footer that expands to fill all the remaining space on the page? [So the footer would be 1800px high if the content only takes up 200px of height on a 2000px high monitor?])

Answer (score 0):

You could add a dummy div and style that with CSS to match the height of your navigation pane, with your footer below this div, it'll always style the way you want.
It would be better if you did use some JavaScript, it wouldn't be complicated at all.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you'll need to clear the footer, by applying `clear:both;` in css selector for the footer.

Answer (score 0):

would suggest going for the js alternative..seems much easier..please tell us if there's any specific reason to avoid js based styling in your case...the only other alternative i could think of is hardcoding the body content div dimensions and setting the footer position fixed..not ideal

Comment: The most obvious reason to avoid JavaScript-based styling is that a surprising number of users, usually 5-10%, have JavaScript disabled.